# Two seperate IF functions in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I am trying to set up a finance spreadsheet and want to combine this:

```
=IF(E4="HSBC",G3-D4,+G3)
```

with

```
=IF(O4="HSBC",G3+N4,+G3)
```

in order to have two separate columns for income and outgoings.

Is there anyway in which I can use both of these in one cell, independent of one another?

Comment: What're you trying to output in that single cell?

Comment: The current balance of the account.

e.g. If I input £50 into income the cell will increase by 50 and vice versa for outgoings.

Comment: So, if `E4` and `O4` are `HSBC`, what do you want to do? At the very least, you can do `=IF(E4="HSBC",G3-D4,+G3)&", "&IF(O4="HSBC",G3+N4,+G3)`

Comment: If E4 is HSBC then decrease G3 by the value of D4. 
If O4 is HSBC then increase G3 by the value of N4.

Comment: It seems to mess up the value in the account with that formula. Any suggestions? (Have added a photo to question for reference)

Comment: I'm just not quite clear - in your screenshot, what value do you expect to be in `G4` and `G5`?

Comment: £417 as it would be 1000-584+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something along the lines of

```
=G3-@IF(E4="HSBC",D4,0)+@IF(O4="HSBC",N4,0)
```

But I'm sorry, I'm not in a position to troubleshoot the exact command/syntax for you at this time.

Comment: What does the `@` do in the formula?

Comment: @BruceWayne Apparently, it's a no-longer-needed way to indicate "this is a function."  I guess you can leave it out.